# How iterating on std::map returns sorted elements based on the key value

Tags: c++, sorting, iteration, stdmap

The container std::map is a data structure that STL provides. In almost all compilers it is implemented as a R&B tree with guaranteed log(n) insertion, find and removal time.

In a red and black tree the elements are sorted based on the "less" operator of the stored element. So basically if a root is N + 1 , N will be on the left sub-tree while N + 2 will be on the right sub-tree and this ordering will be decided by the less operator.

My question is when executing the below code:

```
  std::map<char,int> testMap;

  testMap['a']=10;
  testMap['b']=30;
  testMap['g']=50;
  testMap['d']=70;
  testMap['h']=23;
  testMap['f']=44;
  testMap['c']=100;
  testMap['e']=10;

  typedef std::map<char, int>::iterator it_type;
  for(it_type iterator = testMap.begin(); iterator != testMap.end(); iterator++) {
      std::cout << iterator->first << std::endl;
  }
```

**This is the output of the code:** 
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h

The elements are returned in a sorted order based on the key value. How can this be possible considering the fact that the underlying data structure is a red and black tree? How c++ iterates from the leftmost sub-tree to rightmost sub-tree is it a doubly linked r&b tree?

Comment: That's a bizarre question. The reason that you see the elements come out in key order is because the Standard requires the ordered map to present its elements in key order, and that's it. Implementers have to implement their libraries so that the specification requirements are met. If they choose to use an RB tree, then they have to use it in such a fashion that it produces the required order.

Comment: ok standard might require that but I am more interested in the implementation, how this behaviour is implemented in a R&B tree?

Comment: Do you just... not know how to traverse a tree? It's a really simple, commonly taught algorithm. I don't see where your surprise is coming from.

Comment: It sounds like you could pick up any text book or tutorial on algorithms and data structures and learn about red-black trees. I'm not sure what this question has to do with C++.

Comment: The implementation details are not defined by the standard. But the code is available just look in the header files provided by your compiler.

Comment: a simple pre-order traversal of any tree would return the sorted elements in the tree, that is ok. But when iterating on it, when I get an iterator on the begin element of the map, which element I am pointing to? It seems that I am pointing to the leftmost element since I get the lowest value first. And then from there how I am iterating to the rightmost element if it is only possible to iterate from root to child in a normal tree structure? Is it clear?

Comment: @ralzaul: if it were only possible to "iterate from root to child in a normal tree structure", then you may indeed be confused; however, that sounds like a completely unfounded assumption. Please study the tree data structure more carefully; you will learn eventually that you can navigate between nodes in many ways (parent, child, sibling, ...).

Comment: Your assumption about iterating only one way in a tree is false assumption.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22861986/2642059

Comment: guys I know what a tree is quite well and of course a tree which it is possible to iterate in both directions is possible to implement but it is not the naive implementation of a tree :) Then basically the answer to my question is : it is a doubly linked tree which it is possible to go from child node to parent node and vice-versa?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree - `n->parent`

Comment: @ralzaul: Could be, or the iterator could use a stack to track unvisited subtrees, or it could do anything else that satisfies the standard's requirements. If you want to know what a particular implementation does, read that particular implementation's source code.

Comment: this is the answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, there are two ways to iterate through the contents of a tree: breadth first and depth first. Breadth first looks at all the elements at one level before going down to the next level. Depth first goes down one branch of the tree to it's leaf, then comes up and back down to the next leaf, etc. For a tree that represents **sorted** data, depth first can give you the data in sorted order, and that's what `map` iterators do, because it's most useful.