# How are keys arranged in ascending order in stl maps?

Tags: c++, stl, maps

When i iterate through maps in for loops

```
for(auto it : my_map )
cout << it.first << "\n" ;
```

How do i get an ordered list , when the data is actually stored in form of a balanced tree . Also how is time complexity of this operation O(n) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is std::multimap Really Just Nested Vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861986/is-stdmultimap-really-just-nested-vectors)

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. Traversing a tree in order is ready. Given you get N results the complexity must be at least O(N); why would it be more?

Comment: @JonathanMee hi , i dont think the two questions are similar , i am well aware of maps being implementation of bst , my question asks how is the bst traversed such that we have data ordered in an ascending order . For example if an array was sorted , we can simply imagine traversing [0]-->[1]-->[2]-->.....-->[n] . But in case of a binary tree , the data is simply not arranged so simply for me to think how iterator goes from from one node to another when we use the loop i mentioned above...hope my question is a bit clearer now:) .

Comment: hi @AlanStokes pls read my comment for jonathan. I can only know what the time complexity for the operation is when i know the operation itself :p , that btw was my question too , how the bst is travarsed in such a way that we move through data in ascending order(with respect to   key)  when using the given for loop .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  A `map` is indeed implemented as a balanced tree (usually implementations choose a red-black tree).  All nodes throughout the tree hold values (i.e. not just leaf nodes), and they're sorted such that the "left" branch from any node contains only values "less than" the node's own value, with the "right" branch containing greater values.

For example:

```
           m
         /   \
        f     q
       / \   / \
      c   h o   t
         /
        g
```

To traverse the tree, you initially start at C which must be tracked by a pointer in the map object itself, otherwise begin wouldn't be O(1).  Then from any given node, iteration is simply a matter of doing the first of the following 3 options that applies:

1) *if you're already at the right-most node*, which the map object must also track, stop; *otherwise...*

2) *if there is one* go to the right child, then follow its "left child" pointers down as far as possible, *otherwise...*

3) follow the links back to parent / grand-parent etc. nodes until you find the node you've just ascended from is the left node of its parent (at which point that parent's node value will be greater than any of the nodes you've ascended from; note it's consistently cheap to compare pointers/links, so that's better than comparing key values which can be expensive for some types)

- for example, when you ascend g to h, you'll have come from a left-child node, so should stop at h; then on the next iteration you'll ascend first to f but see you haven't come from the left-child so keep ascending f-to-m, which is from the left child, so that will be your next stop during iteration

> Also how is time complexity of this operation O(n) ?

Say you draw a tree on paper and write in arrows to show how you traverse the tree using the logic above, you'll see you only ever have one descent following any given "left child / parent" link followed by one ascent through the same link.  Therefore, the number of link traversals is < 2n, and the number of comparisons is even smaller - so clearly O(n).

Comment: hi your answer is exactly the way i wanted :)...but i was having some trouble in following the three steps . By the steps you have written, i am not exactly traversing the way i actually should, i.e c-->f-->g-->h-->m...and so on (ascending order) . Also i noticed there was no step written for what i should do if there as no right child .  :)

Comment: @95_96: as far as I can see, they do traverse properly - "no steps written for what I should do if there [was/is] no right child" suggests I didn't explain clearly enough that for any given increment of the iterator you only follow the first of the three instructions that applies. So if there's no right child, you fall through to step 3 - going to the parent etc...  I've reworded the answer to (hopefully) make that clearer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get a list of the map keys in order.  I think that the following would work:

```
std::vector<map_type::key_type> keys;
std::transform(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), std::back_inserter(keys),
               [](map_type::value_type const& v){return v.first;});
```

It will run in O(n) since it is iterating directly over the linked collection.  Looking up an element by key would be logarithmic but iteration is O(n).